# ًWhat are the sins that was stated in Duaa Kumail?

Tags: shiism, dua, sin

In [Duaa Kumail ben Ziad](http://najafi.yoo7.com/t2923-topic) you can read this:

> اَللّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي الذُّنُوبَ الَّتي تَهْتِكُ الْعِصَمَ،
> اَللّـهُمَّ اغْفِـرْ لِي الذُّنُوبَ الَّتي تُنْزِلُ النِّقَمَ،
> اَللّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي الذُّنُوبَ الَّتي تُغَيِّـرُ النِّعَمَ،
> اَللّـهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لي الذُّنُوبَ الَّتي تَحْبِسُ الدُّعاءَ،
> اَللّـهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي الذُّنُوبَ الَّتي تُنْزِلُ الْبَلاءَ،
> اَللّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لي كُلَّ ذَنْب اَذْنَبْتُهُ، وَ كُلَّ خَطيئَة
> اَخْطَأتُها
>
> O Allah, forgive me such sins that affront my continency;
> O Allah, forgive me such sins that bring down calamity; O Allah,
> forgive me such sins that change divine favours into disfavours; O
> Allah, forgive me such sins as would hinder my supplication; O Allah,
> forgive me such sins that bring down afflictions; O Allah, forgive me
> such sins that suppress hope; O Allah, forgive every sin that I have
> committed and every error that I have erred.

My question could be divided to multiple points:

1. What are the sins that affront my continency?
2. What are the sins that bring down calamity?
3. What are the sins that change divine favours into disfavours?
4. What are the sins that would hinder my supplication?
5. What are the sins that bring down afflictions?
6. What are the sins that suppress hope?

Comment: I appreciate your nice query which indeed was my question as well. God bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sins that affront continency: drinking of Swizzle; gambling; doing things which cause pointless laugh like Ranting and jesting; caviling and saying that to others; Companion with kofar, profligates and Skeptics.
2. Sins that bring down calamity: Disobedience of gnostic (Aref) person (which disobey while she/he has cognition) and his/her proud against people and his/her people mocking.
3. Sins that change divine favours into disfavours: oppression to people, quitting from good habits, quitting from [Enjoining good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enjoining_good_and_forbidding_wrong)(amre be maroof),Ingratitude of favours, leave to be thankful of Allah(they are mentioned in Quran:

> "Indeed, Allah will not change the condition of a people until they
>   change what is in themselves"surah Ar-Ra`d,verse11

4.sins that would hinder my supplication:having bad purposes,having foul Conscience,being hypocritical with Muslims, being hopeless about dua accepting,delay to praying till its time pass,avoiding to Take approach of Allah with doing good acts(kheirat),being scurrilous.

5. Sins that bring down afflictions:avoid helping of Oppressed person,leaving of [Enjoining good and forbidding wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enjoining_good_and_forbidding_wrong).
6. Your Arabic text doesn't include " O Allah, forgive me such sins that suppress hope".see:http://www.duas.org/pdfs/dua-e-kumayl.pdf

Sins that suppress hope: being hopeless about Allah’s Mercy and his favours, leaning to others than Allah, denial of Allah’s Promise.

Reference :([Imam Ali ibn Husayn Zayn al-Abidin(a.s.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_ibn_Husayn_Zayn_al-Abidin) in book Ma'ani al-Akhbar from [Al-Shaykh al-Saduq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Babawayh).)